# Would a cat be considered a "bestia"?

Tags: vocabulary

I am trying to understand what the word "bestia" meant. Did it have the same connotations as the English word "beast" and the Croatian word "zvijer"? Would somebody who likes cats call cats "bestiae"? Would somebody who hates cats call cats "bestiae"?

Comment: Re-opened following the edit. Just to clarify something that Joonas said, a question *in* Latin is acceptable, so long as it's also *about* Latin. The way I read the original is that it seemed more like it was asking an opinion about cats. That's why it was closed (and, I presume, why someone downvoted it).

Comment: What I've seen some people do in other questions is to have a parallel text with Latin and a translation, in case the Latin fails to convey the question properly. You still could translate your above question to Latin for practice, so long as you're not also asking for help on that (you would ask about that separately).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Going off the [L&S entry for *bestia*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dbestia1), I think the answer is more subtle than "yes" or "no." *Bestia* can signify different things in different contexts.

### More generic sense

In one sense, *bestia* refers to a non-rational animal. In this sense, *homo* and *bestia* exhaustively and exclusively divide the genus *animal*:

> quod si hoc apparet in **bestiis**, volucribus nantibus agrestibus, **cicuribus feris**, primum ut se ipsae diligant—id enim pariter cum omni animante nascitur —deinde, ut requirant atque appetant ad quas se applicent eiusdem generis animantis—idque faciant cum desiderio et cum quadam similitudine amoris humani—quanto id magis in **homine** fit natura, qui et se ipse diligit et alterum anquirit, cuius animum ita cum suo misceat, ut efficiat paene unum ex duobus! (Cicero, *Laelius de Amicitia* 81)

My translation:

> And if this is apparent in **beasts**, whether in air, water, or land, whether **tame or wild**--first, that they love themselves (for this arises at the same time with every animate being) and next, that they seek and pursue beasts of the same animate kind in order to attach themselves to them (which they do with desire and with some likeness of human love)--how much more does this happen by nature in **man**, who both loves himself and seeks another, so that he may so unite his soul to the other's that he practically makes one soul out of two!

What is significant about this passage (cited in L&S) is that the contrast is between *bestia* (which includes the subgroups of *cicur* (=tame) and *fera* (=wild) and *homo*.

In this sense, even a *canis* (dog) can be called a *bestia*:

> **canes** aluntur in Capitolio ut significent si fures venerint. at fures internoscere non possunt, significant tamen si qui noctu in Capitolium venerint et, quia id est suspiciosum, **tametsi bestiae sunt**, tamen in eam partem potius peccant quae est cautior.  (Cicero, *Pro Roscio Amerino*, 56)

My translation:

> Dogs are fed in the Capitol that they may alert if thieves have come. But they cannot distinguish thieves, yet they alert if any people have come into the Capitol at night and, since that is suspicious, even though they are beasts, still they rather err on the side that is more cautious.

In *this* sense, I would make an *a fortiori* argument that if a *canis* is a *bestia*, then so too is a *feles* (cat).

### More specific sense

In another sense, *bestia* refers to a wild animal *as opposed to* a domesticated animal or farm animal. Here, for instance, is a quote where a *canis* is explicitly opposed to a *bestia*:

> pastor album [custodem] probat, quoniam est ferae dissimilis, magnoque opus interdum discrimine est in propulsandis lupis sub obscuro mane uel etiam crepusculo, **ne pro bestia canem feriat**. (Columella, *de Re Rustica* 7.12)

My translation:

> A shepherd values a white [guard dog], because it doesn't resemble a wild [beast], and occasionally much care is needed when fighting back wolves in the darkness of morning or even of dusk, **so that he doesn't wound the dog instead of the beast**.

(Note: in 2.9, Columella will also explicitly distinguish between two kinds of dogs: those which are *ferae bestiae silvestres* (i.e. wolves), and domesticated dogs.)

There are several more examples I found like this one where *bestiae* are opposed to *pecudes*. Here's one of the most explicit mentions I could find:

> sed canis inter pecudes non est. longe magis bestiae in eo numero non sunt, ueluti ursi leones pantherae. elefanti autem et cameli quasi mixti sunt (nam et iumentorum operam praestant et natura eorum fera est) et ideo primo capite contineri eas oportet. (*Digesta Iuliani* IX.2: *Ad Legem Aquiliam*)

My translation:

> But a dog is not in the class of cattle. All the more beasts are not in that group, e.g. bears, lions, panthers. But elephants and camels are like mixed kinds (for they provide the work of beasts of burden and their nature is wild) and therefore they should be contained in the first chapter.

I interpret the *longe magis* here as indicating that a *bestiae* and *canis* aren't overlapping categories. It also is significant only a *lion* (not a generic cat) is put in the category of *bestiae*.

### In short

In one (perhaps more philosophical) sense, a beast covers any non-rational animal. In another (more everyday) sense, a beast singles out wild animals.

In the latter sense, a dog is *not* a *bestia*, and it seems reasonable to suppose that a domesticated cat wouldn't be either.

I cannot find a case (yet) where a *feles* is explicitly called a *bestia* (in the first sense) or distinguished from a *bestia* in the latter sense. Herodotus appears to be using the first sense when he talks about Egyptian household cats (αἴλουρος) as beasts (θηρίον):

> πολλῶν δὲ ἐόντων ὁμοτρόφων τοῖσι ἀνθρώποισι **θηρίων** πολλῷ ἂν ἔτι πλέω ἐγίνετο, εἰ μὴ κατελάμβανε τοὺς **αἰελούρους** τοιάδε. (Herodotus, *Histories* 2.66)

My translation:

> Though there are many domestic (lit.: nourished with men) **beasts**, there would be even more if the following didn't happened to **cats**.

Comment: Might be worth a note that Columella is writing some time after Cicero, and is specifically concerned with farm life. It could be a difference between ordinary usage and specialized usage.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a cat (*feles* or *faelis*) is a *bestia*. For example:

(walls of enclosures should be high) *...ne faelis aut maelis aliave quae bestia introire possit* ("...so that the cat, the marten or other such beast cannot get in") -- Varro, *On Agriculture*

The Latin word *bestia* is very similar to the English beast and is used much the same way. Just as in English, it usually referred to a wild animal, but can also be a tame animal. Note that [cats were not popular pets in ancient Rome](https://archaeology.co.uk/articles/features/archaeology-of-the-domestic-cat.htm), although they were tolerated as mousers. Dogs were much more common as pets.

The word *bestia* has a somewhat neutral connotation, so could be used either by someone who liked or disliked cats either way. It was only if the word was applied to a person, a *bestius*, that it took on a derogatory tone.

Comment: Good find! I wasn't aware of the alternative spelling when I did a corpus search. I would be careful, though, since L&S cites the passage immediately preceding (in 3.11) as an example of the meaning ["polecat"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_polecat), and that meaning seems to carry over here. I think it would be surprising in a context like this to refer to a domesticated cat or dog as a *bestia* (though the Herodotus parallel might also be a counterexample).

Comment: I looked up two translations online: one has "polecat" and "wild cat" for the two occurrences; the other has "weasel" for both.

Comment: @brianpck In the context it is probably as I have it. Some of the translations of that passage are "dictionary" translations by an academic with no experience on a farm. You do not need a high wall to keep out a weasel. Weasels are 6" tall. Also, I saw a translation that rendered maelis as "badger"--once again betraying a total ignorance of the rural environment and its animals.

Comment: I don't know much about European animals myself, but badgers and polecats certainly eat young rabbits, and polecats can get up to 18" (if Wiki informs me correctly). But the bigger point is that it's generally not a good idea to be dismissive of expert opinions. Translations are often wrong, but some presumption of competence is generally a good idea.